# CSS !important not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and for some reason the `!important` qualifier isn't working.

```
<div style="font-family : calibri; font-size: 20pt !important;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span style="font-size: 11px;">
        <span style="font-size: 11px;">
          Honey Glazed Applewood Smoked Spiral Ham 
        </span>
        <span style="font-size: 11px;">
          Served with Dijon Honey Mustard and Turkey Roulade
        </span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The span tags are generated for website formatting. I was adding the div tag to change the output to PDF format instead of writing a seemingly overcomplicated find and replace function. Since this hack is for specific regions of code, I can't change the CSS sheet.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: This is CSS rather than HTML. I retagged it but hope you could change the title.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, coffee hasn't kicked in yet. Changed.

Comment: This is a good example of why you shouldn't use in-line styles: they can be quite hard to override when you need to. Ideally the <span>s should have a class which is styled to 11px in a separate CSS. If your <div> also had a class or ID, it would then be easy to override the spans.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Give the `<div>` an id and then add this rule to your CSS stylesheet (or in a `<style>` tag if you don't want to change the style sheet):

```
#your_div_id span {
    font-family : calibri; font-size: 20pt !important;
}
```

`!important` in CSS allows the author to override inline styles (since they have a higher precedence than style sheet styles normally).  It doesn't automatically make the style marked `!important` override everything else.

**SEE:** [The W3C's documentation on CSS Selector Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules).
[Felix's Demo of the markup](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ZcXY4/)

Comment: That won't work. I mean, you cannot enforce the bigger font size for the span elements without removing the style information on the elements.

Comment: @Felix -- good point!  I've added the `<span>` to the selector, so now it *should* be specific enough.

Comment: @Sean Vieira: Yes it does and it seems I was too strict ;)

Comment: @Felix King -- *Bows* Glad I can be of some help!

Comment: I will delete my answer (its 50% wrong ;)) so you should change your text too (and not refer to me).

Comment: @Felix - done -- your contribution is now anonymous, as you desire :-)

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain so I can make the answer better?

Answer (score 28):

A good subject to read up on is [CSS Specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)

1. p has a specificity of 1 (1 HTML selector)
2. div p has a specificity of 2 (2 HTML selectors, 1+1)
3. .tree has a specificity of 10 (1 class selector)
4. div p.tree has a specificity of 12 (2 HTML selectors + a class selector, 1+1+10)
5. #baobab has a specificity of 100 (1 id selector)
6. body #content .alternative p has a specificity of 112 (HTML selector + id selector + class selector + HTML selector, 1+100+10+1)