# How to override CSS for TextBoxFor field?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor, html.textbox

Have the following class in Site.css:

```
input[type="textbox"].TextBoxAsLabel {
     background:#f2f3f3  !IMPORTANT;
}
```

want to override default background for TextBoxFor field in Edit.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientNumber, new {@readonly = "readonly", @class = "TextBoxAsLabel"})
```

and it still uses default white background. What should I change?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that problem was in location of CSS file. Now code in separate styles.CSS is:

```
  .message-label {
    background-color: #f2f3f3;
  }
```

Styles.css is referenced in _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and in CHTML:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientNumber, new {@readonly = "readonly", @class ="message-label"})
```

and it works!

Answer (score 6):

There is no `input[type="textbox"]`.
You mean `text`.

Comment: changed to be :  input[type="text"].TextBoxAsLabel {
         background:#f2f3f3  !important;
      } and this is still not working

Comment: @user2911759: Use your browser's inspector to find out why.

Comment: inspector says: <input class="TextBoxAsLabel valid" id="ClientNumber" name="ClientNumber" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="03480A"> there is no background info.what should I change?

Comment: change your CSS.  see the end of my answer

Comment: @Malachi: made change to try excerpt from "Please try this" from the end of Malachi's answer. did not help - same effect

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=text].TextBoxAsLabel
{
   background:#f2f3f3 !important;
}
```

If something overriding then use inline

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientNumber, new {@readonly = "readonly",
              @class = "TextBoxAsLabel", @style='background:#f2f3f3 !important'})
```

Comment: @Malachi that does not says to remove double quotes in `type=text`. for a try i gave that

Comment: made change to be: input[type=text].TextBoxAsLabel {
                 background-color:#f2f3f3  !IMPORTANT;
    } and this did not help either

Comment: You need to use "!important", all lower case. Not "!IMPORTANT"

Comment: @rossisdead, I used lower case only for `important`

Comment: made change to have:                                                     input[type=text].TextBoxAsLabel {
                 background-color:#f2f3f3  !important;
    }                                                                    still not working

Comment: @user2911759, copy & paste `input[type=text].TextBoxAsLabel{background:#f2f3f3 !important;}` and see. or keep the style in inline

Comment: the link to "Working Fiddle", doesn't work. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

when you are dealing with CSS you have to remember that the last thing that applies to that Element is what shows as the final product.

CSS goes Top to bottom, the last thing is the final result.

[order of precedence](http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence)

in this site it looks like you can either use `!Important` or `!important`

it said nothing about all CAPS though

Another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616964/css-important-not-working) about the `!important` override, the answer talks about giving the element an ID or doing some `<style>` tags to implement this style.

**Addition**

I assume that the top set of code is your CSS.  in CSS you need to use Selectors, like if you have a Tag like

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" />
```

then you select it with

```
#btn1
```

you grab by the ID

if you have

```
<input type="button" class="btnClass" />
```

then you can select all the buttons with `btnClass` like this

```
input.btnClass
{
}
```

**Please Try This**

```
input.TextBoxAsLabel {
    background:#f2f3f3  !IMPORTANT;
}
```

OR

```
#ClientNumber input {
    background:#f2f3f3  !IMPORTANT;
}
```

*I think that syntax is correct*

**Also**

this is super simple,  we are all going to put our heads in our hands if this is the answer

the CSS should be

```
background-color:#f2f3f3 !Important
```

and not

```
background:#f2f3f3 !Important
```

Not sure if this is part of the problem but I would also try to Remove `[type=text]` from the selector.

Comment: changed to be :  input[type="text"].TextBoxAsLabel {
         background:#f2f3f3  !important;
      } and this is still not working

Comment: made change to try excerpt from "Please try this". did not help - same effect