# css in javascript important not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the border color of any control in my page using javascript . The color change but then returns back to the original color .
first i tried :

```
control.style.border = "solid 1px red";
```

then I tried  :

```
control.attr('style', 'border : solid 1px red  ');
```

also :

```
addStyleAttribute(control, 'border : solid 1px red  !important');
```

finally  :

```
 var all = document.styleSheets,
 s = all[all.length - 1],
 l = s.cssRules.length;
 if (s.insertRule) {
 s.insertRule('#' + control.id+ ' {border: solid 1px red !important }', l);
 }
```

all of the above  didnt work

any help ?

Comment: Just checking: Does it work if you set the style in your stylesheet?

Comment: "but then returns back to the original color" — When does it does this? It sounds like you are reloading the page, which would wipe out any local DOM  changes.

Comment: my code is on  WebForm_OnSubmit() . on submitting the page the color changes for a few seconds but then 'disappear' .

Comment: @Cerbrus it does not work in the style sheet

Comment: Then there might be something wrong with your CSS instead... What's your current HTML / CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616964/css-important-not-working

Answer (score 1):

> on submitting the page the color changes for a few seconds but then 'disappear'

You are changing the page, then submitting the form, then a new page loads, and the change you made to the old page is not in the new page.

You'll need to make the change in the new page too. Typically you'll want to do this by using server side code in your form handler.