# How to change font-family of the headers, like h2?

Tags: css, fonts, wordpress-theming

This problem is kinda weird:

I've added a new font-family and it is being applied to everywhere in theme, except the homepage intro headings.

I added a code manually (selecting the exact class through inspect element).

```css
.h2.text-heading-default{
    font-family: "tahome";
}
```

And I expect it should solve the problem but the headings are still showing the previous fonts.

What is the solution for this?

Stuff that I tried:

- I used "!important" next to the code above
- Cleared browser cache
- Cleared WP cache
- Checked header.php file for anything like tag or conflict, nothing
  found
- Checked the font family file, it is there and already being applied
  to everywhere in the theme, except the intro headings

Still nothing worked.

Comment: Your problem might be specificity, you can test this by adding a ID to the H2. See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616964/css-important-not-working

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h2.textstyle {
    font-family: tahoma
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<h2 class = "textstyle">Changing text style to tahoma</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Could there perhaps be an error in the name of the text style with it being called 'tahome' because I tried, that it didn't work, but when I did the above code in html, for 'tahoma' it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.h2.text-heading-default {
  font-family: 'tahome' !important;
}
```

Just add '!important' in front of font-family name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the header has a "!important" tag in the font-family css. If so, you can remove the "!important" word in the header css or add "!important" to your class.

Comment: there is no "!important" in the header.php file. Same for the style.css file. I'm using Visual Composer btw

Answer (score 0):

Many People have already answered, but let me tell you again that you need to add !important to it. If this doesn't work, then try simplifying the code.

```
.h2 /* Try writing this only*/ {
font-family: "tahome" !important;
```

}

Also check if there are any mistakes in HTML code. You can post the HTML code in Stackoverflow for re-checking.

And yes, I'm not really sure but if this isn't working, it may be possible that the font-family you installed doesn't support the headings. Try downloading another font=family.

Bye. Have a great day!