# Media Breakpoints are failing

Tags: css, breakpoints, bootstrap-5

I am missing something really simple here so hopefully somebody can unspin my brain.

I have a page layout working OK but on applying the media breakpoints nothing changes. Below is an example of my CSS. You can see I am just altering the font size to try and get the thing working but nothing changes when altering the browser width. The `p` font remains the same size regardless of the browser width.

Importantly - the regular Bootstrap responsiveness and page layout does happen, my own media instructions do not.

```
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}


@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  p {
  font-size: 116%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  p {
  font-size: 108%;
  }
}
```

Another example is a carousel I have added. The media instructions only involve the height of the carousel. But like the example above - the carousel height remains the same no matter the broswer width.

```
#carouselMain {
  height: 460px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  #carouselMain {
  height: 660px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #carouselMain {
  height: 560px;
  }
}
```

Thanks. I don't know why this should happen. A similar question has been asked before but the given answer doesn't seem to apply to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like those often missed dashes and slashes the problem was poor syntax in the CSS immediately before my breakpoints and so the breakpoints weren't being processed properly. I'm clocking out for the next two and a half days.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `!important` after the property?
Like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  p {
  font-size: 116%!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea @IgorGarciaRez ... Worth a try but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey @CuteCodeRob, im sorry to hear that :(  You should consider giving <p> an id like Sergiu answer

Answer (score 0):

Give `<p>` an id and then add this to the CSS stylesheet:

```css
@media (min-width: 400px) { 
  #p{
    color: red;
    font-size:24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

 
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <p id="p">P media</p>
  </div>
```

Or use! Important [w3.org (info)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

```css
@media (min-width: 400px) { 
  .container-fluid > .p{
    color: red;
    font-size: 34px!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

 
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <p class="p">P media</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu .... I can't see the `id` idea working. It doesn't really matter if the breakpoint addresses the `p` tag itself or the `id` within the `p` tag.

Comment: @cute-code-rob why not ? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616964/css-important-not-working`

Comment: I want the change to be global I am not adding an ID to every single `p` tag on the site.